# CS0103: The name 'Encoding' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I have a webapplication running on framework 3.5 and is installed on multiple clients, working perfectly.

Except this one client... where all webservices that the application provide fail with the following error message:

> Compilation Error  Description: An error occurred during the
>   compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please
>   review the following specific error details and modify your source
>   code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Encoding' does not exist in
>   the current context
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 100:    string EscapedFileName { Line 101:        get {  Line
>   102:            return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(FileName, Encoding.UTF8);
>   Line 103:        } Line 104:    }
>
> Source File:
>   c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx
>   Line: 102

Google points me toward the application might be targeting the client version of the framework or the system missing the system.web dll.

I've checked that both this possibilities are not the cause... Any ideas?

Answer (score 62):

Try to use the namespace
using System.Text;

Answer (score 3):

Check your web.config for any **`<clear />`** elements for the namespaces.
Also, check your App Pool settings. If possible, can you create a new App Pool and try again?

Comment: for me there was a webconfig under one of the folders and that one had the clear in the namespaces. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by locating the DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx file at the specified path and adding this to the Imports at the top:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Text" %>
```

In my case, I was also seeing a similar error about `HtmlUtility` not existing, which I was able to fix by adding:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %>
```